# if a[j] is a[j+1]: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
    n = int(input())
    a = []
    i=0
    for i in xrange(n) :
       a.append(raw_input())
    c=0
    j=0
    for j in range(0, len(a)) :
             if a[j] is a[j+1]  :
                  c=c+1
             else :
    print a[j-1], c
    c=0
```

When i run this code in a code editor, the compiler gives an error

```
   if a[j] is a[j+1]:
   IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the fault in it??

Comment: Do `for j in range(0, len(a)-1)` as `j` exceeds the length of the list `a`

Comment: Some tips: Please use more descriptive variable names, don't use `is` to test equality; `is` tests identity so unless you have a list with several of the same instance of an object (`lst= [a,a,b,b,c,c]`) that Boolean will never be `True`. You also don't need to initialize the iterator variables before you sue them so you don't need `i=0` or `j=0`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are exceeding the length of the list. In order to fix this change `len(a)` to `len(a)-1`:

```
for j in range(0, len(a)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` and you run `for i in range(len(list))` it goes through `i = 0` to `i = 4`.
`list[4]` gives you `4` but `list[5]` which is `i+1` does not exist.

So in your code you should change `for j in range(0, len(a)) :` to `for j in range(len(a)-1):`

Also you don't need the `0` in your range because python assumes that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to add the `0` in your for loop:

```
for j in range(len(a)-1) :
```

This will make a range from `0` to `len(a)-2`

Answer (score 0):

In python list index start from 0.
So for a list with n items the index of last item will be [n-1]